# How might I notate that an entity either cannot have a quality or has all of it?

Tags: logic

I have two friends, Charles and Louis.

I want to state that given one of the following conditions then Charles and Louis are identical:

- Charles does nothing.
- Louis does nothing.
- Charles does everything.
- Louis does everything.
- Charles knows nothing.
- Louis knows nothing.
- Charles knows everything.
- Louis knows nothing.

Comment: How is your proposed edit related to the question as currently phrased?

Comment: extreme(a, p) := Exists x: p(a, x) => All x: Domain(p), p(a, x).   Then 'extreme(Charles, knows)', means that if there is anything Charles knows, then for every thing knowable, Charles also knows that.  This implies he knows nothing or everything.  The rest of the question makes no sense to me.  But you might be able to phrase it with conditionals involving 'extreme'

Answer (score 1):

To start with the title of your question, the formalization of "the individual y either P's everything or nothing" is

```
(forall x (P(y,x)) v (forall x (- P(y,x)))
```

The way you phrased your question, your conditions translate as

```
(forall x (- do(c,x)) v
 forall x (- do(l,x)) v
 forall x (do(c,x)) v
 forall x (do(l,x)) v
 forall x (- know(c,x)) v
 forall x (- know(l,x)) v
 forall x (know(c,x)) v
 forall x (know(l,x)))
--> c = l
```

which, using a variable to talk about Charles and Louis simultaneously, can be written more compactly as

```
forall y ((y = c v y = l) -->
          ((forall x (- do(y,x)) v 
            forall x (do(y,x)) v 
            forall x (- know(y,x)) v 
            forall x (know(y,x)))
           --> c = l))
```

meaning

> If for any of Charles or Louis we have that he either does nothing or does everything or knows nothing or knows everything, then Charles and Louis are identical.

**This is doing what you said -- the statement is true iff at least one of the conditions is true --, however, it is a rather strange way to define identity**. Why would, for example, Louis being omnicient imply that he is identical to Charles if we know nothing about Charles? By your last condition, Louis knowing everything would be enough to make the conclusion that they are identical true, but this seems hard to accept intuitively.

**Rather, one will probably want to say that Charles and Louis are identical if they know and do all the same things**: If, for everything that can be done, if Charles does it then Louis does it and vice versa, and for everything that can be known, if Charles knows it then Louis knows it and vice versa; then Charles and Louis are identical. (This includes the limit cases where either of them knows/does everything or nothing at all, but also captures the intermediate situations where they do/know some things and others not, as long as those things that they do do/know are the same between them.) The formalization of this is

```
(forall x ((do(c,x) <--> do(l,x)) ^ (know(c,x) <--> know(l,x))) --> c = l
```

which is not what you said, but probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One way to formalize it would be

```
(forall x)(Ax & Dca -> (forall y)(Ay -> Dcy))
```

Which means

> For any x, if x is an action and Charles does x, then for any y, if y is an action then Charles does y.

So as long as there is one action that Charles does, Charles will do any action whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is asking whether Charles and Louis are identical given a list of properties, it may be related the identity of indiscernibles.

Wikipedia describes it as

> The identity of indiscernibles is an ontological principle that states that there cannot be separate objects or entities that have all their properties in common. That is, entities x and y are identical if every predicate possessed by x is also possessed by y and vice versa; to suppose two things indiscernible is to suppose the same thing under two names.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles#Identity_and_indiscernibility) provides two ways of notating this idea depending on what one is trying to say:

> There are two principles here that must be distinguished (equivalent versions of each are given in the language of the predicate calculus). Note that these are all second-order expressions. Neither of these principles can be expressed in first-order logic (are nonfirstorderizable).
>
> 1. The indiscernibility of identicals
>
>    - For any x and y, if x is identical to y, then x and y have all the same properties.
>
> ∀x∀y[x = y → ∀P(Px ↔ Py)]
>
> 2. The identity of indiscernibles
>
>    - For any x and y, if x and y have all the same properties, then x is identical to y.
>
> ∀x∀y[∀P(Px ↔ Py) → x = y]
>
> Principle 1 doesn't entail reflexivity of = (or any other relation R substituted for it), but both properties together entail symmetry and transitivity (see proof box). Therefore, Principle 1 and reflexivity is sometimes used as a (second-order) axiomatization for the equality relation.
>
> Principle 1 is taken to be a logical truth and (for the most part) uncontroversial. Principle 2, on the other hand, is controversial; Max Black famously argued against it.

In the above two notations *P* ranges over the list of properties in the OP's question and any others that might apply. The variables *x* and *y* would be Charles and Louis.

If Charles is identical to Louis then Charles and Louis have the same properties. That is the "indiscernibility of identicals" in the first principle. The second principle, the "identity of indisceribles", claims that if Charles and Louis have the same properties then they are identical.

As Wikipedia notes the second principle is controversial.

---

Wikipedia contributors. (2019, May 14). Identity of indiscernibles. In Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Retrieved 19:44, May 16, 2019, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Identity_of_indiscernibles&oldid=896988126